# RegEx Partial string matching

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible in PHP Regex to do partial matching so that if I have an array like:

```
$words = array("john", "steve", "amie", "kristy", "steven");
```

and I supply "jo" it would return "john" or if "eve" is supplied, it returns "steve"?

Comment: why regex? Why not `strpos("john", "jo")`?

Comment: because when a search term is supplied, it should return a best match. strpos requires I know the word to compare against

Comment: You just said the word to compare against was `jo`. So iterate over the array and see where `strpos()`  doesn't return `False`. I fail to see the problem.

Comment: @TimPietzcker nevermind I'm retarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$words = array("john","jogi", "steve", "amie", "kristy", "steven");
foreach ($words as $value) {
    if (preg_match("|jo|", $value)) {
        $arr[] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

This will return you array with john and jogi

Comment: it is working , tell me one thing for eve will return steve and steven na? or you want only first match answer would be returned..

Comment: did you see the codepad link? I used codepad to execute your php code and it returns "null" and several warnings

Comment: I am sorry @dukevin ,I don't know why its not working in codepad ,but I am bit confident it is working in php ,I have tested using netbeans and php.

Comment: I found some post based on warning just go through it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859363/warning-preg-match-internal-pcre-fullinfo

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to find a substring, either use [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) (for case-sensitive search) or [stripos](http://php.net/stripos) for case-insensitive search.

If you need regex, then you can specify wildcards at both ends: `/.*jo.*/` which will force it to always match "dojo", "jo", "joe", "dojos", etc.

To search in an array for your pattern, look at [preg_grep](http://uk.php.net/preg%20grep) - this lets you pass in a regex (`/.*jo.*/`) as the first parameter, and an array as the second (`$words`), and returns any elements which match your regex.

Comment: That just makes processing the regular expression more expensive.

Comment: I don't think he's worried about efficiency, from the answer he's accepted

Comment: That doesn’t mean you should propose inefficient solutions.

Comment: Well I'm sorry for trying to offer advice. I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through your array and match your items using [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php).
If you don't supply a `^` and `$` it automatically does partial matching.