# Regex on 10kB variable -> empty response from server

Tags: php, apache2, preg-match-all

I'm trying to grab all url's in a big css file.

I tried using this regex:

```
preg_match_all("/url\('(\\'|[^'])*'\)/m", $css, $matches);
```

`$css` is a 10kB variable, read from a css file using `file_get_contents`.
`$matches` is an empty array.

However, this results in a `(net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)` error in chrome: the server doesn't send any data. If i return the function just before this line, everything works fine. If i return the function just below this line, I get an empty response.

It doesn't even send the data I outputted before that line, and it responds (with an empty response) within a few seconds - nowhere near the 30s timeout.

It worked just fine when I first used this regex, and passed the output to the above code. 
    `preg_match_all("/@font-face{[^}]+}/m", $css, $matches);`
That row was before I realized I needed the other URL's - not only the fonts.

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong?

UPDATE:
Could it be this bug?
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62049
links to:
http://codepad.org/FmlJi8N9
and a quick google search later:
[Warning: preg_match(): Internal pcre_fullinfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859363/warning-preg-match-internal-pcre-fullinfo)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try matching line by line, url would unlikely spread for two lines.

Comment: server logs give you any hints?

Comment: Found nothing in the logs. Also, `explode(PHP_EOL, $subject);` and a `foreach` didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
preg_match_all("/url\([^)]*\)/m", $css, $matches);
```

Comment: That worked! Do you see any reason to why my crappy regex failed?

Comment: Well, mine is a simple greedy expression, will read just as match as needed, so there's no chance for a timeout. Not quite sure about yours... what was your intention with `\\'`?

Comment: To allow escaped quotes in the path. I noticed that we're using a combination of ', " and no quotes, so I modified the code to match that as well. Your regex fits nicely into the new code.