# Error condition when using preg_match in php?

Tags: php

I have a sample string:

```
revision
revision-2
revision-3
revision-n...
autosave
```

and php code

```
if(preg_match('/revision/', $str)) {
   echo "Edit 1";
}elseif(preg_match('/revision-(.+?)/', $str)) {
   echo "Edit $1";
}else {
   echo "Auto save";
}
```

But result null, how to fix it?

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2013/10/understanding-regular-expression.html#more
This is the best and easiest regular expression tutorial can help you in debugging

Comment: What do you mean by "result null"? This code echoes "Edit 1" when I execute it. What is is you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: "Result null"? What does that mean?

Comment: maybe You have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859363/warning-preg-match-internal-pcre-fullinfo ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
if(preg_match('/^revision-(?[0-9]+)$/', $str, $matches)) {
   echo "Edit ". $matches[0];
} elseif(preg_match('/revision/', $str)) {
   echo "Edit 1";
} else {
   echo "Auto save";
}
```

Explanation:

- ̛'^' means 'starts with'
- (? ) tells the regular expression to save the
  match it encloses
- [0-9] means all characters from 0 to 9
- '+' means one or more times
- '$' means 'ends with'

Put that all together, and you have a regular expression meaning
If the string contains only 'revision', a dash, and a number, save the number and output it as the Edit number. Otherwise output 'Auto Save'.

Answer (score 1):

You're not capturing your pattern anywhere. You need to do that:

```
$str = 'revision-14';
if(preg_match('/revision-(.*)/', $str, $matches)) 
{
   echo "Edit ".$matches[1];
}
elseif(preg_match('/revision/', $str)) 
{
   echo "Edit 1";
}
else 
{
   echo "Auto save";
}
```

also note, that `/revision/` is less restrictive, so you need to place more-restrictive condition first

Answer (score 0):

1. The first `if(preg_match('/revision/', $str))` will match *all* the cases except "autosave". You may want `/^revision$/` to match "revision" exclusively.
2. I guess you expect `echo "Edit $1"` to output the `(.+?)` match. That's not how it works. You have to capture the match using the third argument to `preg_match`:

   ```
   if (preg_match('/revision-(.+?)/', $str, $match)) {
       echo "Edit $match[1]";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

You could use explode to find the value. If your output remains the same that is.

`$match = end(explode('-', $str));`

This will assign the value after '-' to $match.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem in pattern string

hope below pattern will resolve ur problem.

preg_match('\'revision-2\'', 'revision
revision-2
revision-3
revision-n...
autosave', $matches);

There is one useful online link is also available to Perform a regular expression match. This can also be helpful for you :

http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

Happy Coding :)